# Stop darkmode from flickering JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a website with a lightmode/darkmode switch. 
It uses local storage to remember user's choice, so next time they come back , their preferred theme is loaded.

The style change happens with the help of css variables.

Here is the JS

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 
const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById('dark-mode-toggle');


const enableDarkMode = () => {   
  document.body.classList.add('darkmode');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {
   document.body.classList.remove('darkmode');
   localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}

if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
   enableDarkMode();
}


darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');     
  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
   enableDarkMode(); 
  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});
```

The problem is: When you go from one page to another, the page flashes the light theme first and then goes dark. How do I prevent the light mode css from loading first if the user picked darkmode?

*NOTE: I am aware that there is a similar question answered here on SO, HOWEVER, the solution did not work for me.

Comment: You can try flipping the default state of the CSS. It takes a little bit of time before the JS runs. A dark flash when the user uses light mode might be better than a light flash when the user uses dark mode.

Comment: How about also using a cookie to be able to set the class name from the server side?

Comment: @ZacharyHaber I would like it not to flash at all..

Comment: @Gabriel never worked with cookies, so wanted to see if there was another option before I go into exploring cookies

Comment: The problem is that no matter how you store the setting, it takes time to download the page, execute your code, look into the internal storage and set the class. I think the only way to improve it is to send the html with the theme already set from the server, so it loads immediately (other than controlling the navigation "ajax-style" so it doesn't actually navigate to a different page, like youtube). I think cookies would be the easiest way.

Comment: @Gabriel yeah...I guess it's time to learn about cookies. Thanks  :)